# Transferir informação de uma View para Outra

Tags: sqlite, xamarin-forms, mvvm

Boa tarde! 
Me deparei com uma duvida, estou desenvolvendo um projeto xamarin forms shared, utilizando padrão MVVM, em uma determinada View Model1 ligada a View1, ao efetuar uma pesquisa e existindo o valor no banco local, a View Model1 Chama a View2. Até ai tudo bem, minha duvida é como passar esses valores pesquisados na View1 para a View2. Essa foi uma forma que encontrei de resolver em partes essa questão, pois a pesquisa realizada pelo código de barras de um produto, verifica no banco se o produto existe, se existir, retorna o Nome e o valor do mesmo, gostaria de trazer essas informações em uma segunda View aonde possa adicionar também a quantidade de itens que quero e retornar um somatório de quanto irá custar.

Comment: Sobre a duvida postada, em vez de passar a informação de uma tela para outra, resolvi inserindo diretamente no banco de dados. Na outra tela, apenas recupero estas informações e efetuo as inserções que estão faltando. Como solução para o que havia solicitado, me orientaram a usar o mesenging Center. Não testei essa situação para ver o quanto é valido, mas se alguém precisar, pode estar verificando: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/messaging-center/.

Comment: Você pode passar o objeto no construtor da view também. O messaging center é interessante quando você quer informações de uma tela para ser usada em outra, por exemplo... Sobre a sua solução, eu aconselharia você a considerar se essa é a melhor estratégia, uma vez que se o app for fechado após você sair da primeira tela, você terá um registro inconsistente no banco